# Does Skype for Ubuntu automatically update by itself like Windows or Mac OS X?

Tags: skype

I know the "Check for updates" option is turned on by default, but would that update it automatically or would I still have to it manually?

Skype was installed from the website.

Comment: Does Skype work, and what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Virusboy Skype works, and I am talking about Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed Skype from the repositories, you'll get updates when the repo maintainers release the update; typically days or weeks after Skype issues an update.  If you installed Skype direct from the Skype site (either the tarball method or the .deb download), then it'll update when Skype issues updates, which, however, is significantly less frequent for Linux than for Windows.

Comment: In the latter case, are you saying that it updates automatically "when Skype issues updates"? If so, how?

Comment: Sorry, I was a little unclear; no, as I recall (been a while since I had an update), it won't automatically update.  It will update itself, but you have to manually tell it to check from the Skype menu.  Given no more frequently than Skype updates the Linux client, it shouldn't be a big burden, but it's not something you can easily automate (as you might with system updates).  I seem to recall it'll remind you when you log in, also, if there's an update available.